# MVP and RxJava - Handling Orientation Changes on Android

Tags: android, rx-java, screen-orientation, rx-android

Im using MVP and RxJava similar to [google-samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-rxjava/) repo.

And I would like to ask how to correctly handle screen orientation change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is another strategy that enables saving presenter state and also `Observable`'s state: [retain `Fragment`](http://bcorso.github.io/android-retain-fragment/). This way you omit standard Android way of saving data into `Bundle` (which enables only to save simple variables and not the state of network requests.)

`Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityView {
    private static final String TAG_RETAIN_FRAGMENT = "retain_fragment";

    MainActivityPresenter mPresenter;

    private MainActivityRetainFragment mRetainFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initRetainFragment();
        initPresenter();
    }

    private void initRetainFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mRetainFragment = (MainActivityRetainFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_RETAIN_FRAGMENT);
        if (mRetainFragment == null) {
            mRetainFragment = new MainActivityRetainFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mRetainFragment, TAG_RETAIN_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }
    }

    private void initPresenter() {
        mPresenter = mRetainFragment.getPresenter();
        mRetainFragment.retainPresenter(null);
        if (mPresenter == null) {
            mPresenter = new MainActivityPresenter();
        }
        mPresenter.attachView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            mRetainFragment.retainPresenter(mPresenter);
            return;
        }
        mPresenter.detachView();
        mPresenter = null;
    }
}
```

Retain `Fragment`:

```
public class MainActivityRetainFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivityPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void retainPresenter(MainActivityPresenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public MainActivityPresenter getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

Notice the way activity lifecycle events are handled. When the `Activity` is created, retain `Fragment` is added to the backstack and on lifecycle events it is restored from backstack. retain `Fragment` does not have any view, it is just a holder for presenter during configuration changes. Notice the main invocation that enables restoring exactly the same fragment (and it's content) from backstack:

```
setRetainInstance(true)
```

If you are concerned about memory leaks: every time the presenter is restored presenter's view is restored:

```
mPresenter.attachView(this);
```

So the previous `Activity` reference is replaced by new one.

More about such handling of configuration changes here [here](http://androidsrc.net/handle-android-asynctask-configuration-change-using-fragment/)

Answer (score 1):

I handled by encapsulating view's state in specific ViewState class in presenter, and it is easy to test.

```
public interface BaseViewState {
    void saveState(@NonNull Bundle outState);

    void restoreState(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState);
}

class HomeViewState implements BaseViewState {

    static final long NONE_NUM = -1;

    static final String STATE_COMIC_NUM = "state_comic_num";

    private long comicNum = NONE_NUM;

    @Inject
    HomeViewState() {
    }

    @Override
    public void saveState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putLong(STATE_COMIC_NUM, comicNum);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            comicNum = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_COMIC_NUM, NONE_NUM);
        }
    }

    long getComicNumber() {
        return comicNum;
    }

    void setComicNum(long comicNum) {
        this.comicNum = comicNum;
    }
}
```

get/set values from viewState in presenter, this helps to keep it updated, as well as presenter stateless.

```
public class HomePresenter implements HomeContract.Presenter {

    private HomeViewState viewState;

    HomeViewState getViewState() {
        return viewState;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadComic() {
       loadComic(viewState.getComicNumber());
    }
    ...
}
```

in Activity as View should initiate call to save and restore.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements HomeContract.View {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
            homePresenter.getViewState().restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }


        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);

            homePresenter.getViewState().saveState(outState);
        }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But its a possible to save Observable like timer for example to Bundle?